# Do tokens work with Rules "Set a data value"?

Tags: entities, rules, tokens

I have a simple Rule created in which the action is that a particular entity is created (a node) and then another action is called to "Set a data value" of one of this node's field (a standard text field). In the Rules action I setup the tokens that I want to be put as data into this field. For some reason the tokens are not showing up properly when the entity is created:
[image]
[image]

I have tried a few different combinations but as you can see above the token I am using (node:author:link) does not display properly when the node is created. What is the reason for this? I have experimented with all of the different input filters but it does not seem to work for any of them.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my own question and thought I'd share. The solution is to use [Token Filter](https://drupal.org/project/token_filter) module. Once you have installed this module got to: Admin > Config > Content Authoring > Text Formats. Create a new Text Format or edit an existing one and you will see an option called "Replace Tokens", check this and save your format. Now when your are using "Set Data Value" make sure that the text field has the input format that you just created/changed.

You should now be able to pass tokens successfully using Rules Set Data Value and they will format correctly.